# How i increase and decrease value inside anchor tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination

How i increase and decrease @currentpage value inside anchor tag with MVC Razor?

```
@{
    double pagesize = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(@ViewData["count"]) / 10);
    int currentpage = Convert.ToInt32(@ViewData["id"]);
}
<a href="/Home/Index/@currentpage-1">Prev</a>
<a href="/Home/Index/@currentpage+1">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="/Home/Index/@(currentpage-1)">Prev</a>
<a href="/Home/Index/@(currentpage+1)">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 @{
        double pagesize = Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(@ViewData["count"]) / 10);
        int currentpage = Convert.ToInt32(@ViewData["id"]);
        int nextpage=currentpage+1;
        int Prevpage=currentpage-1;
    }
    <a href="/Home/Index/@Prevpage">Prev</a>
    <a href="/Home/Index/@nextpage">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried but something like this should work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next", "Index", "Home", new { id = (Convert.ToInt32(@ViewData["id"]) + 1) }, "")
@Html.ActionLink("Prev", "Index", "Home", new { id = (Convert.ToInt32(@ViewData["id"]) - 1) }, "")
```